# problem in Adding image in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using this code in mVC2 and it is working Fine for me. But when i convert it into mvc3 this code give me error. Please tell me how i convert it into mvC3. The code is

```
<% Html.Grid(Model.MemberPagedList).Columns(column => {
 column.For(x => x.Id).Named("Id");
       column.For(x => x.message).Named("Message").Action(p =>
       { %>
       <td> some image tag here
       </td>
                     <td style="display: none; "  id =<%= p.Id%>>
                     <%= p.LogMessage  %>
                 </td>

                <% });
        }).RowStart((p,row)  => {     
             if (row.IsAlternate) { %>
                   <tr >
             <%  }  else  { %>
                 <tr>
             <% }
    }).Sort(Model.GridSortOptions).Attributes(@class => "table-list").Render(); %>
```

I am Replacing `<% %>` with `@` But it is not working. I am not able to understand how i write Html Code ie `<td>.....</td>`

```
<td style="display: none;" id=<%= p.Id%>>
    <%= p.LogMessage  %>
</td>
```

in mvc3

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom column to add an image to an MVCContrib Grid:

```
@(Html
    .Grid<MyViewModel>(Model.MemberPagedList)
    .Columns(column =>
    {
        column.For(x => x.Id);

        column.For(x => x.LogMessage);

        column
            .Custom(
                @<text>
                     <span>@item.LogMessage</span>
                     <img src="@Url.Action("image", new { id = item.Id })" alt="" />
                 </text>
            )
            .Named("Message");
    })
    .Sort(Model.GridSortOptions)
    .Attributes(new Hash(@class => "table-list"))
)
```